# Publish post's date is set to Nov 30 -0001

Tags: posts, admin

It is very difficult for me to describe the problem and the cases when it happends.

The idea is that somtimes Publish date of article in administration panel is set to "Nov 30, -0001 @ 0:00". 
The status is set to Published and even when press Update of given post, the date still is set to that mysterious date with year -0001. This happens with custom post type.

Does anyone have any ideas how to investigate or fix the problem?